# HP M605 making Tray 2 the default

Tags: printing

I have a HP M605 with the open tray feed (#1), and the two other trays (#2, which is directly under the tray feed), and (#3, which is directly under tray #2).  Is there a way to make tray #2 the default tray instead of tray # 3?